# Построить дерево из строк

Tags: php, алгоритм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как построить дерево из строк? Имеется массив:

```
$arr = [
  'FOLDER1',
  'FOLDER2', 
  'FOLDER2|FOLDER3',
  'FOLDER2|FOLDER4',
  'FOLDER2|FOLDER4|FOLDER5',
  'FOLDER6|FOLDER7', 
  'FOLDER8',
  'FOLDER8|FOLDER9'
];
```

Нужно получить массив вида:

```
$output = [
    [
        "short" => "FOLDER1",
        "full" => "FOLDER1",
        "sub_folders" => []
    ],
    [
        "short" => "FOLDER2",
        "full" => "FOLDER2",
        "sub_folders" => [
            [
                "short" => "FOLDER3",
                "full" => "FOLDER2|FOLDER3",
                "sub_folders" => []
            ],
            [
                "short" => "FOLDER4",
                "full" => "FOLDER2|FOLDER4",
                "sub_folders" => [
                    [
                        "short" => "FOLDER5",
                        "full" => "FOLDER2|FOLDER4|FOLDER5",
                        "sub_folders" => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "short" => "FOLDER6",
        "full" => "FOLDER6",
        "sub_folders" => [
            [
                "short" => "FOLDER7",
                "full" => "FOLDER6|FOLDER7",
                "sub_folders" => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "short" => "FOLDER8",
        "full" => "FOLDER8",
        "sub_folders" => [
            [
                "short" => "FOLDER9",
                "full" => "FOLDER8|FOLDER9",
                "sub_folders" => []
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм в принципе не хитрый, подобные задачи в принципе встречались тут не единожды.

Следует просматривать каждую строку отдельно, и разбивать ее с помощью `explode()` на части. Результирующий массив для упрощения алгоритма можно сделать изначально вида `['full' => "", 'subfolders' => []]`.

Дальше для каждой строки надо строить дерево. Тут принцип прост и встречается (в т.ч. на этом ресурсе) не редко. Вы просто идете по массиву, и при этом сохраняете ссылку на предыдущий элемент, вроде `foreach($data as $d){ .....; $prev = &$d; }` и имеете доступ к родительскому элементу на каждой  итерации. Это позволит простым циклом строить ветку дерева, ведь вам именно это и требуется.

```
$result = ['subfolders' => [], 'full' => ""];

foreach($arr as $s){
    $data = explode('|', $s);
    $p = &$result;

    foreach($data as $k){
        if(!array_key_exists($k, $p['subfolders'])){
            $p['subfolders'][$k] = [       // добавили дочерний элемент 
                    'short' => $k,.
                    'full' => $p['full']."|$k",.
                    'subfolders' => []
                 ];
        }
        $p = &$p['subfolders'][$k];         // ссылка на родителя
    }
}

$result = $result['subfolders'];
```

Единственное, в данной реализации полный путь  начинается с `|`. Думаю, с этим вы и сами разберетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```
foreach($arr as $row){
      foreach( explode('|',$row) as $val){
          # здесь генерим массив с проверкой на subfolders
          $tmp=['short'=>$val,'short'=>$val];
          if(count($val)==2){}
          if(count($val)==3){}
          $out[]=$tmp;
      }
}
```

Comment: я бы сказал.  очевидно, что вложенность не будет ограничена 2 или 3мя элементами.

Comment: @teran, может в конкретной задаче вложенность ограничена 3 элементами, ну если нет то нужна рекурсия